# After installing KB4480970 I cannot access shared folders or printers

Tags: windows-7, networking, network-shares

I just installed KB4480970 on my Windows 7 computer `LAB-PC`. Now none of the other machines on my network can access the folders and printer I have shared from this computer.

Everything was working fine before the update. Turning off the Windows firewall didn't help. I can ping `LAB-PC` from other computers.

If I try to access my share "Test" on LAB-PC from another computer by typing `\\LAB-PC\test` into Explorer's address bar, I get the error:

> Windows cannot access \\LAB-PC\test

I tried mapping a drive to LAB-PC by running `net use Z: \\LAB-PC\test` and got the error:

> System error 6 has occurred.
>
> The handle is invalid.

[image: System error 6 has occurred. The handle is invalid.]

I'm running Windows 7 Pro 64-bit. My computer is not in a domain. How can I fix this?

Comment: The proposed duplicate is asking for *general advice* what to do when updates "like" this one break your computer. Quote: "...in general what should I do in these situations?" It does not describe the symptoms specific to this patch and is unlikely to be found by users searching for these problems.

Comment: They are still connected and related, it's important to link, relevant issues to one another.  The linked question was specifically about the issues caused by `KB4480960` and `KB4480970` and honestly don't see anything generic about the linked question.  By submitting the same answer to two questions you have caused an interesting issue.

Comment: I agree that proposed duplicate is general. found this one by searching for the specific "System error 6 has occurred".   Otherwise I'd still be wrestling my pc and close to accepting defeat.

Comment: This issue also causes authentication to fail with Visual Studio's Remote Debugger. Hotfix KB4487345 also fixes it.

Comment: I had the same error with a server accessing shares in Azure Files.  Sharing tips here in case it helps the future folk.  This troubleshooter script: https://github.com/Azure-Samples/azure-files-samples/tree/master/AzFileDiagnostics/Windows - flagged that the system couldn't access its own admin share (e.g. `\\localhost\c$`).  That led me to discover that some registry settings were missing: fixed via steps here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-server/networking/problems-administrative-shares-missing#resolution

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is a [known issue](https://www.computerworld.com/article/3332202/microsoft-windows/patch-tuesday-updates-for-win7-kb-4480970-and-kb-4480960-knock-out-networking.html) caused by the January 8, 2019 Windows Update [KB4480970](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4480970/windows-7-update-kb4480970). According to Microsoft this update introduces the following issue:

> Local users who are part of the local “Administrators“ group may not be able to remotely access shares on Windows Server 2008 R2 and Windows 7 machines after installing the January 8th, 2019 security updates. This does not affect domain accounts in the local "Administrators" group.

On January 11 Microsoft released [hotfix KB4487345](https://www.catalog.update.microsoft.com/Search.aspx?q=KB4487345) to resolve this issue:

> This update resolves the issue where local users who are part of the local “Administrators“ group may not be able to remotely access shares on Windows 7 SP1 and Windows Server 2008 R2 machines after installing the January 8th, 2019 security updates. This does not affect domain accounts in the local "Administrators" group.

This hotfix is not being distributed via Windows Update. Instead, you must [download](https://www.catalog.update.microsoft.com/Search.aspx?q=KB4487345) it directly from the Microsoft Update Catalog website.

Install this hotfix on the computer *hosting* the network share(s) that users are not able to access. According to my testing it's not necessary to install it on computers *from* which one is trying to access the shared folders or printers.

Comment: KB4480960 causes the network share problems also.

Comment: ah for the love of dog.  I've been fighting my PC for two days.  Nearly re-installed all. Thanks for the post. Fixed it good in my case.